# Advice on how to attend the auction at the Tsukiji fish market in Tokyo

Tags: budget, japan, transportation, tokyo, sleeping

I'm very aware of [this question about the Tsukiji fish market](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6204/what-are-my-chances-of-getting-into-the-tsukiji-fish-auction-if-i-arrive-by-525) but I'd really like to be there in time for the auction so that I can take pictures of it. Since the first train is at 5am and I don't want to take a taxi, what are other cheap options to get there in time?

I thought about spending the night in one of those internet cafes with good couches to sleep (I don't quite remember the Japanese name). Do you know any good one around the Tsukiji? Any other advice?

Comment: There is a bicycle rental system that covers Akasaka/Tsukiji and many other places of Tokyo. I believe it is usable at night, and much cheaper than a taxi. It might be a bit complex to use as a tourist though. http://docomo-cycle.jp/tokyo-project/en_index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which way is the best to get there is highly depending on where you are coming from. Since Tsukiji is very close to Shimbashi, you can use the Yamanote Line to get there and then walk. The first train arrives there around 4:30. From Ueno for example, at 4:45. [Hyperdia](http://www.hyperdia.com/) offers a search engine in English on this.

If you want to stay in an internet Cafe, there is a map of all [MangaKissa shops around Tsukiji](http://mobile-netcafe.com/station/02500). Finding the right spot is tricky. Not all places offer flat beds, and some are open only to members. Also, without speaking Japanese, you will have issues using these places. There might be also registration fees.

[This one here](http://www.geragera.co.jp/store/shinbashi.html) seems to be open to non-members (but members can get some discounts), have a flat seat and is quite close to Tsukiji, again at the Shimbashi train station. [Google also translates this page](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http://www.geragera.co.jp/store/shinbashi.html).

It will be hard to find anything closer since the Tsukii area is not considered a major train station and therefore not the best area to build these shops. However, if you are willing to walk 30-45 minutes, you can also look around Ginza and Shidome.

Comment: Thanks mate, a lot of useful informations! I didn't specify where I'm gonna stay since I don't know yet, but to me seems that most of the cheap hostels are locate in Akasaka area so I will probably end up there.

Comment: You could just walk from Akasaka. Probably the easiest! http://goo.gl/maps/EwMc0